# selecting only distinct row based on highest timestamp on a join

Tags: mysql

I perform a join on these two tables in mysql

Challenges table

```
challenge_ID(int) |to_user(int)|from_user(int)|timestamp
```

Users table

```
iduser(int)|email(string)
```

My join query is this :

```
 Select distinct u.email,c.challenge_id,c.status,c.timestamp from 
 test.challenges c join test.users u
 on 
  c.to_user=u.iduser 
 where 
  c.from_user=9 and (c.status='open' || c.status='rejected') 
 Order by 
  c.timestamp DESC
```

The result what I get from this query is

```
email           |challenge_id| status    |timestamp (Descending)
Dan21@rab.edu       5           open      2015-12-09 21:20:26
tommy52@gump.com    4           open      2015-12-09 21:10:22
Dan21@rab.edu       1           rejected  2015-12-08 12:27:00
```

Notice how Dan21@rab.edu is repeated twice, I want it to display only once and the one displayed should have the latest timestamp  i.e.

```
email           |challenge_id| status    |timestamp (Descending)
    Dan21@rab.edu       5           open      2015-12-09 21:20:26
    tommy52@gump.com    4           open      2015-12-09 21:10:22
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write your query as:

```
Select u.email, c.challenge_id, c.status, c.timestamp
from test.challenges c join
     test.users u
     on c.to_user = u.iduser 
 where c.from_user = 9 and c.status in ('open', 'rejected') 
 Order by c.timestamp DESC;
```

Don't use `select distinct` unless necessary.  Then you can do what you want in various ways.  Because you have a `join` and other conditions, I think variables might be the simplest way:

```
select cu.*
from (Select u.email, c.challenge_id, c.status, c.timestamp,
             (@rn := if(@e = u.email, @rn + 1,
                        if(@e := u.email, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from test.challenges c join
           test.users u
           on c.to_user = u.iduser cross join
           (select @e := '', @rn := 0) params
       where c.from_user = 9 and c.status in ('open', 'rejected') 
       order by u.email, c.timestamp DESC
      ) cu
where rn = 1;
```

EDIT:

I thought the above worked with `join` and the variables in a single query.  But, sometimes MySQL gets confused and you need to use a subquery with variables:

```
select cu.*
from (select cu.*,
             (@rn := if(@e = u.email, @rn + 1,
                        if(@e := u.email, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from (Select u.email, c.challenge_id, c.status, c.timestamp,
            from test.challenges c join
                 test.users u
                 on c.to_user = u.iduser 
            where c.from_user = 9 and c.status in ('open', 'rejected') 
            order by u.email, c.timestamp DESC
           ) cu cross join
           (select @e := '', @rn := 0) params
      ) cu
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: I have never use variable before ,I am trying to understand the query you gave 

I ran it on my db and It seems its returning the same(groups the email id tho) but rn remains 1 for all rows  and it returns all the 3 rows

Comment: I find this hard to follow as I don't use mysql(or RDs for that matter) much other basic queries . I copy pasted this in my phpadmin and it gave me a syntax error near the first join 

I figured out a query join using a sub query ,I have posted it on the answer. I have not tested it much but apparently it serves the purpose 

Kindly let me know if that is not the most efficient way to do this

Answer (score 0):

I figure out a query for this which works , not sure if its foolproof or most efficient way to do this

Here it is tho

```
      Select distinct u.email,c.challenge_id,c.status,c.timestamp
            from
                (select ch.challenge_id,ch.status,ch.from_user,ch.to_user,timestamp,
                    (select Max(timestamp) from challenges 
                        where to_user=ch.to_user
                        and from_user=9
                    ) as latest 
               from test.challenges ch 
                )c
            join test.users u
            on
                c.to_user=u.iduser
            and
            c.latest=c.timestamp
    where (c.status='open' || c.status='rejected')
```